# When i click the menu in drop down, How can i be able to pass value and hit second api?

Tags: reactjs

```
export default App;
```

**How do i pass value to second api**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

let App = () => {
  let [value, setValue] = useState('');
  let [locations, setLocations] = useState([]);


  let handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (value === "") return;

    let response = await axios.get(`https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/locality?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=${value}`);
    if (response.status === 200) setLocations(response.data);
  }
  let handleChange = async () => {
    if (value === "") return;

    let response1 = await axios.get(`https://api2-4ofagodxfq-uc.a.run.app/branch?stateName=KARNATAKA&districtName=BANGALORE&pinCode=560001&officeName=${value}`);
    if (response1.status === 200) setLocations(response1.data);
  }

  return <div>
    STATE:<select value="KARNATAKA">
      <option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    CITY:<select value="BANGALORE">
      <option value="BANGALORE">BANGALORE</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    PINCODE:<input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} onKeyPress={(handleSubmit)} />
    <br />
    <select onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value1)} >
      {locations.map((location, index) => {
        return <option key={index}>{location}</option>
      })}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" onClick={(handleChange)}></input>
    {locations.map((location, index) => {
      return <p key={index}>{location}</p>
    })}

  </div>
}

export default App;
```

*That too in the same page*

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap all form fields in `<form />` call `handleSubmit()` on submit

something like  this

```
<form submit={() => handleSubmit()}>
STATE:<select value="KARNATAKA">
      <option value="KARNATAKA">KARNATAKA</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    CITY:<select value="BANGALORE">
      <option value="BANGALORE">BANGALORE</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    PINCODE:<input type="text" onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} onKeyPress={(handleSubmit)} />
    <br />
    <select onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value1)} >
      {locations.map((location, index) => {
        return <option key={index}>{location}</option>
      })}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" onClick={(handleChange)}></input>
    {locations.map((location, index) => {
      return <p key={index}>{location}</p>
    })}
</>
```

Comment: But it will not hit second api

Comment: it should, did you try it? do u have it in codesandbox ?

Comment: yes I tried. It will hit the first api and repeats the result in <p>